# Rails: Averaging an array of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array like so: `["18:45", "18:45", "18:58"]`

Here is the method I am using to average the times:

```
  def avg_of_times(array_of_time)
    size = array_of_time.size
    avg_minutes = array_of_time.map do |x|
      hour, minute = x.split(':')
      total_minutes = hour.to_i * 60 + minute.to_i
    end.inject(:+)/size
    "%s:%s" % avg_minutes.divmod(60)
  end
```

If I run that same method above in an `irb` console, the average comes out just fine, but in Rails, it comes out like so: `18:148/3`

What could be causing this method to no function properly in rails?

```
Rails version: 3.2.14
Ruby version: 1.9.3-p429
```

Comment: Works for me in `Rails 3.2.12`, `Ruby 1.9.3p448`

Comment: That's so odd, I can't get it to run to save the life of me... if I run `3/4` in a debugger console it prints `(3/4)`

Comment: You have a Integer becoming a Rational (x/y): 148/3 = 49,33 #=> How to represent that? Can you try `avg_minutes.divmod(60).map(&:to_i)`? --Also works for me Ruby 1.9.3p448 && Rails 3.2.11

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Can you add your comment as an answer? That solved my issue!

Comment: `"%s:%s" % avg_minutes.round.divmod(60)` should fix it. Or replace `round` with `floor` or `ceil` as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works in my IRB console, `Rails 3.2.11` and `Ruby 1.9.3-p448`.

---

The problem is that you are getting a float number in your calculation, and this one is turned into a Rational object (to solve the endless .33 decimals). I would try this:

```
def avg_of_times(array_of_time)
  size = array_of_time.size
  avg_minutes = array_of_time.map do |x|
    hour, minute = x.split(':')
    total_minutes = hour.to_i * 60 + minute.to_i
  end.inject(:+)/size
  "%s:%s" % avg_minutes.divmod(60).map(&:to_i)
                                  #^^^^^^^^^^^ here is the new part
end
```

Or like @Matt suggested, just rounding the total amount of minutes **may solve** your problem:

```
"%s:%s" % avg_minutes.round.divmod(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem not with rails itself. Probably some library (may be `mathn`)  redefines `/` to use `Rational` or something like this. There described [some workaround](http://makandracards.com/makandra/11781-workaround-for-broken-integer-division-after-requiring-the-mathn-library) to avoid problem.

Comment: We are using the `ruby-units` gem... wonder if thats whats causing it

Comment: @dennismonsewicz as your comment saying "3/4 results in a Rational object 3/4 in [your] console", in my console 3/4 returns 0 (3.0/4 returns 0.75) -> So I would say yes, your gem ruby-units is propably causing this (turning Floats into Rationals)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question has been answered.  Here's an alternative approach:

```
  #require 'active_support'

  a = ["18:35", "19:07", "23:09"]
  avg = a.inject {|tot, str| tot + Time.parse(str).seconds_since_midnight}/(a.size.to_f).round
  mins = avg.divmod(60).first
  hours = mins.divmod(60).first
  hours.to_s + ':' + (mins-hours*60).to_s # => "20:17"
```

Answer (score 1):

`"%d:%02d" % avg_minutes.divmod(60)`

This has two advantages:

- It works when avg_minutes is a `Rational` object.
- It formats the minutes as two digits. So you get "18:01" rather than "18:1".